# I want to input event with react-native-calendars

Tags: react-native, calendar, expo, react-native-calendars

I used expo and react-native-calendars.
I want to display like this picture, but it is difficult for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53nnq.png)

I edited the theme part of react-native-calendars.

```
<Calendar
   theme={{
    'container': {
        innerWidth: 100,
        innerHeight: 100
    },
    'stylesheet': {
        'calendar': {
            'main': {
                monthView: {
                    flex: 1,
                    height: '100%',
                    justifyContent: 'space-around'
                },
                week: {
                    flex: 1,
                    marginVertical: 0,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-around'
                },
                dayContainer: {
                    borderColor: '#f5f5f5',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    flex:1,
                },
            },
        }
    },
}}/>
```

But it didn't look like the grid calendar I imagined.

If anyone knows how to write code that allows you to write events in a grid pattern using react-native-calendars, please comments.

Comment: In stackoverflow, you should show your code instead of a picture

Comment: do you test the example https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/example/src/screens/calendarScreen.tsx?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I tried the example, but it wasn't that the calendar I can write events and isn't a grid pattern.